# Why there's a wide space to the left of my site?

Tags: html, css

A very  wide space to the left of the site's html appears in the browser.I don't know the reason or even when that happened.
I uploaded my site live here : http://kfs-saintgeorge.esy.es/

And here's my CSS file :

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

html{
    direction: rtl; 
    background-color: #b7b7b7;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

img{
    max-width:100%;
}

body{
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

div{
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.centering{
    text-align: center;
}


#hbackground{
    background: url('/images/background.jpg') no-repeat  ;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top:37.01527614571093%;

}

.btop{
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
}

#header ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #1e7989;
    font-family: hfont;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    z-index: 1;
    margin:10px auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#header li{
    width: 9em;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #1e7989;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}


#header li a{
    display: block;
    line-height: 70px;

}

.content {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.content p {
    width: 85%;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-family: contentfont;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 23px;
    color:#862222;
}

a:link, a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#ffffff;
}


h2{
   color:#187477;
   font-family: headlinefont;
   font-weight: normal; 
   text-decoration: underline;
   text-align: center;
}

.mainmenu {
    cursor: pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border:0;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
}

.submenu  {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #17243e;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: none;
    border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
}

.submenu li {
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.submenu li:last-child, .submenu li:last-child a:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;

}

.submenu a:hover {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    color: #000000;
}


nav{
    width: 29%;
    display: inline;
}

nav div{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#sidebar{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: contentfont;
}

#sidebar>ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;

}

#sidebar>ul >li{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #1a8891;
    border:2px solid #0c383a;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#sidebar a:link,#sidebar a:visited{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#sidebar li:hover{
    background-color: #156b72;
}

#body2{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items:flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#main_content{
    width: 70%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#footer{
    background-color: #05333b;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family: Arial;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;

}

#footer p{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);   
}

#cp_widget_e6374685-0d11-4dc4-9b95-04f8435cd872{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

#homeImages{
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;

}

.mainmenu i{
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    top:10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    body{
        width: 100%;
    }

    header ul{
        font-size: 5px;
    }
}

#social{
    direction: ltr;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.social{
    color:black;
    padding: 3px;
}

.fb:hover{
    color:#000098;
}

.yt:hover{
    color: #ff0000;
}

#facebook-page{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fb-page{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem. Please add a Snippet with the minimal amount of code to reproduce the problem and add images to help illustrate your bug. Also, I noticed that rapidly moving the cursor from side to side across the menu rapidly produces a rather nasty effect which you may wish to address.

Comment: Yes ! That's because of jQuery .mouseenter() and .mouseleave() event handlers.Is there a way to fix that problem ?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure but try not using event listeners; call the function from the attributes "onfocus" and "onblur." I'm sure this will have propped up before on SO, so just have a look around if I'm wrong ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see it is because
`direction: rtl` tag in your HTML element.

Try to put it inside `#body2`:

```
#body2 {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue.
but why direction:rtl in html cause that to happen ?

Comment: It applied `right-to-left` direction to the whole site - all elements, not only text. If you look at the `#body2`, applying `direction: rtl` changes the layout of your div as well, so it does not only work for texts.